# Bourbon Refill Navigation DropDown example issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, sass, bourbon

I am using the Bourbon SCSS/SASS navigation menu example from their site:  http://refills.bourbon.io/  (Code pasted at the bottom of this message to retain in case of edit on bourbon site)

I change the first line in the SCSS code:

```
  $navigation-padding: 1em;
```

to say 10em.

This results in the shifting of the nav items 10em to the left.

When I go to the drop-down menu in firefox everything works OK.
Try the same thing in chrome and there is a very limited range that will keep focus on the drop-down menu and if you leave that narrow range the menu disappears (this when moving very slowly).  In addition, even when staying within the narrow range and moving the cursor along the items, the drop-down will disappear after the first item or so.

How can I get it to function properly in chrome?

Note: is there any jsfiddle-like way to demo the code for easy editing?

EDIT:

I found that since I was using the other example from the same page where the device (some smartphone) is oversized in relation to its container div that this is what caused the menu to disappear in chrome. In firefox it works just fine. It has to do with the transform in the .device class (I know this because removing it will have it working). I will leave the question up in case anyone can find a solution.

HTML:

```
<header class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="logo">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/placeholder_logo_1.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="navigation-menu-button" id="js-mobile-menu">MENU</a>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul id="navigation-menu">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link more"><a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Submenu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another Item</a></li>
            <li class="more"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Item with submenu</a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub-submenu Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="more"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another submenu</a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub-submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">An Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-tools">
      <div class="search-bar">
        <div class="search-and-submit">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Enter Search" />
          <button type="submit">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/search-icon.png" alt="">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sign-up">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "base/base";
@import 'neat/neat';

header.navigation {
  $navigation-padding: 1em;
  $navigation-background: $dark-gray;
  $navigation-color: transparentize(white, 0.3);
  $navigation-color-hover: white;
  $navigation-height: 60px;
  $navigation-nav-button-background: $base-accent-color;
  $navigation-nav-button-background-hover: lighten($navigation-background, 10);
  $navigation-nav-button-border: 1px solid lighten($navigation-nav-button-background, 20);
  $navigation-search-background: lighten($navigation-background, 5);
  $navigation-search-border: 1px solid darken($navigation-background, 5);
  $navigation-active-link-color: transparentize(white, 0.5);
  $navigation-submenu-padding: 1em;
  $navigation-submenu-width: 12em;
  $horizontal-bar-mode: $large-screen;

  background-color: $navigation-background;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darken($navigation-background, 10);
  height: $navigation-height;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;

  .navigation-wrapper {
    @include clearfix;
    @include outer-container;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  .logo {
    float: left;    
    max-height: $navigation-height;
    padding-left: $navigation-padding;
    padding-right: 2em;

    img {
      max-height: $navigation-height;
      padding: .8em 0;
    }
  }

  // Mobile view

  .navigation-menu-button {
    color: $navigation-color;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: $sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: $navigation-height;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    @include media ($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      display: none;
    }

    &:hover {
      color: $navigation-color-hover;
    }
  }

  // Nav menu

  .nav {
    z-index: 9999999;
    float: none;
    @include media ($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      float: left;
    }
  }

  ul#navigation-menu {    
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; // stop webkit flicker
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;

    @include media ($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }

  // The nav items

  ul li.nav-link {
    background: $navigation-background;
    display: block;
    line-height: $navigation-height;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: .8em;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;

    @include media ($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      background: transparent;
      display: inline;
      line-height: $navigation-height;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: auto;
    }

    a {
      color: $navigation-color;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 400;

      @include media ($horizontal-bar-mode) {
        padding-right: 1em;
      }

      &:hover {
        color: $navigation-color-hover;
      }
    }
  }

  .active-nav-item a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $navigation-active-link-color;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
  }

  // Sub menus

  li.more.nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      padding-right: $navigation-submenu-padding;
    }

    > ul > li:first-child a  {
      padding-top: 1em;
    }

    a {
      margin-right: $navigation-submenu-padding;
    }

    > a {
      padding-right: 0.6em;
    }

    > a:after {
      @include position(absolute, auto -.4em auto auto);
      content: '\25BE';
      color: $navigation-color;
    }
  }

  li.more {
    overflow: visible;
    padding-right: 0;

    a {
      padding-right: .8em;
    }

    > a {
      padding-right: 1.6em;
      position: relative;

      @include media($large-screen) {
        margin-right: $navigation-submenu-padding;
      }

      &:after {
        content: '›';
        font-size: 1.2em;
        position: absolute;
        right: $navigation-submenu-padding / 2;
      }      
    }

    &:hover > .submenu {
      display: block;
    }

    @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      padding-right: .8em;
      position: relative;
    }
  }

  ul.submenu {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 0;

    @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      left: -$navigation-submenu-padding;
      position: absolute;
      top: 1.5em;
    }

    .submenu {
      @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
        left: $navigation-submenu-width - .2em;
        top: 0;
      }
    }

    li {
      display: block;
      padding-right: 0;

      @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
        line-height: $navigation-height / 1.3;

        &:first-child > a {
          border-top-left-radius: $base-border-radius;
          border-top-right-radius: $base-border-radius;
        }

        &:last-child > a {
          border-bottom-left-radius: $base-border-radius;
          border-bottom-right-radius: $base-border-radius;
          padding-bottom: .7em;
        }
      }

      a {
        background-color: darken($navigation-background, 3);
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;

        @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
          background-color: $navigation-background;
          padding-left: $navigation-submenu-padding;
          text-align: left;
          width: $navigation-submenu-width;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Elements on the far right

  .navigation-tools {
    @include clearfix;
    display: block;
    padding-right: $navigation-padding;
    padding-left: $navigation-padding/2;
    clear: both;
    background: #505050;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      background: transparent;
      float: right;
      clear: none;
    }
  }

  a.sign-up {
    margin-top: 1.2em;
    float: right;
    @include transition (all 0.2s ease-in-out);
    display: inline;
    background: $navigation-nav-button-background;
    border-radius: $base-border-radius; 
    color: white;
    font-size: .8em;  
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: .4em .5em;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      padding: .5em 1em;
    }

    &:hover {
      background: lighten($navigation-nav-button-background, 10);
    }
  }

  // Search bar

  .search-bar {
    $search-bar-border-color: $base-border-color;
    $search-bar-border: 1px solid $search-bar-border-color;
    $search-bar-background: lighten($search-bar-border-color, 10);

    padding: .85em .6em; 
    float: left;
    .search-and-submit {
      position: relative;

      input[type=search] {
        background: $navigation-search-background;
        border: $navigation-search-border;
        padding: .6em .8em;
        font-size: .9em;
        font-style: italic;
        color: $navigation-color;
        border-radius: $base-border-radius * 2;
        margin: 0;

        @include media($large-screen) {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      button[type=submit] {
        @include button(simple, lighten($navigation-search-background, 10));
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.3em;
        right: 0.3em;
        bottom: 0.3em;
        left: auto;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0 15px;

        img {
          height: 12px;
          opacity: .7;
        }
      }
    }

    @include media($horizontal-bar-mode) {
      width: 16em;
      position: relative; 
      display: inline-block;

      input {
        @include box-sizing(border-box);
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JS: (Not necessary in this context)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menu = $('#navigation-menu');
  var menuToggle = $('#js-mobile-menu');
  var signUp = $('.sign-up');

  $(menuToggle).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle(function(){
      if(menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.removeAttr('style');
      }
    });
  });

  // underline under the active nav item
  $(".nav .nav-link").click(function() {
    $(".nav .nav-link").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active-nav-item");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active-nav-item");
    $(".nav .more").removeClass("active-nav-item");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what you had to remove to make this work? I'm having the same exact issue and can't seem to fix it.

Comment: @KraigH its kind of old - i really don't remember how I fixed it.  This is likely one of those browser quirks.  Just try doing it a different way :D

Comment: @KraigH ask a different question if you wish.  I will try to help.  Post the link here

Comment: @KraigH i remember how i fixed it.. *I built my own*